# Navicat MySQL Query Column is null when joining two tables(customer and order table relationship)

Tags: mysql, left-join, navicat, table-relationships

[image: Query]

as you can see in the image the custom created column "customer" is null, but when I use the `RIGHT JOIN` is shows up, but then the idOrder is nulled...

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any null values in your customer table, if there is any null values in the strings, the result of concat will be null too.